# navigation padding vertically

Tags: html, css

i have a navigation bar and i am positioning it absolute, i have a problem with the padding on it, the top and bottom padding are not taking effect on the anchor tag, only the left and right, any idea why this might be occurring?

```
<nav class="main-nav">
    <ul class="main-nav-links">
        <li class="main-link"><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
        <li class="main-link"><a href="#">ABOUT US</a></li>
        <li class="main-link"><a href="#">ORDER</a></li>
        <li class="main-link"><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Here is the css for the nav:

```
.main-nav {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    margin-left: 290px;
}

.main-link {
    list-style: none;
    background-color: #1281f4;
    display: block; 
    float: left;        
}

.main-link > a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #073a4f;
    padding: 1em;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `display: inline-block;` to the `<a>`.

The way it is, it is rendered as a piece of text, and as such, it can't have vertical padding.

An alternative would be to use `line-height`;

Here's a demo: **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MightyPork/dwJzK/)**.

Answer (score 0):

try this

http://jsfiddle.net/xdpHJ/

CSS

```
.main-nav {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    margin-left: 290px;
}
.main-link {
    list-style: none;
    background-color: #1281f4;
    display: block;
    float: left;
}
.main-link > a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #073a4f;
    padding: 1em;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! although why do you need to apply the inline-block to the anchor tag for this to work?

Comment: @user1265535 I answered first and explained it, so look at my answer too.